# Is it possible in Mysql to count number of columns for a given id that have values on it

Tags: mysql

I have searched a lot, but couldn't find any solution for this specific problem. I have a table named `header`, and the structure looks like this(with some sample value)

```
 id   name     choice1     choice2    choice3    choice4     choice5

 1    AAA      Book        Movie      Fishing    
 2    XXX      Music       Dine       Dancing    Flirting
 3    CCC      Food        Music      Pub Night
```

I need to know the number of columns that are filled with values. So, for `id 1`, I want to get `5` .for `id 2`, I want to get `6`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a conditional expression:

```
select t.*,
       ((id is not null) + (name is not null) + (choice1 is not null) + (choice2 is not null) +
        (choice3 is not null) + (choice4 is not null) + (choice5 is not null)
       ) as NumColumnsWithValues
from table t;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context, with "true" being 1 and "false" being 0.  Just adding the results gives the value you want.  In other databases, you would need to use a `case` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Is it possible anyway to use one expression for all choice field,as it is incrementing by 1?

Comment: Can you please pls tell me how can I echo the summed value?Do I have to do mysqli_num_fields to get total number after the query?

Comment: whenever I use mysqli_fetch_row or mysqli_fetch_assoc,I get parameter error.It says,"mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"

Comment: But just because you can, it does not follow that you should.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't know what'd you talking about.Can U pls clarify your point?

Comment: This is a miserable solution. As Andrew says, the proper approach is to normalize your design.

Comment: Trust me,if I go with that approach,that would be whole lot of work in my case(for the project).So,I can't follow that.And,yes,I do know about `database normalization`.Thank you very much for your suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

A better database design would be to have a table for names and a table for choices. Then you can do something like:

```
SELECT n.id, COUNT(c.id)
FROM n
JOIN c ON c.uid = n.id
```

The term is 'database normalization' and a little reading now will save you days of anguish later.